# Get Data From firebase Realtime database using angular http

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, http, get

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase using angular httpClient 
[image: firebase database]

my code to get the data :

    **Service**

```
getUsers() {
return this.http.get(this.fireBase+"/users.json").map(res => {
  const data = res;
  return data;
});
```

**Component**

```
getUsers() {
this.getWeather.getUsers().subscribe(
  (response: any) => {
    console.log(response);
  },
  err => console.log(err)
)
}
```

the result is : 
[image: result in the console]

what I want is to get those objects without keys . I was trying to push them in array. but failed.
can anyone help please.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem by converting the object to array 
here's the code :

```
getUsers() {
this.getWeather.getUsers().subscribe(
  (res: any) => {
    this.users = Object.keys(res).map((key) => { return res[key] });
    console.log(this.users);
  }
)
}
```